# PHP script issue expects exactly 0 parameters, 1 given | mySQL PHP

Tags: php, mysql

The keep receiving the error: `expects exactly 0 parameters, 1 given` when the following script is being executed. The issue is most likely due to the syntax but I am unsure of where to make the edit.

```
<?php

// Create connection
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","username","password","dbname");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())

{
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$return = ['error' => false];
$query = 'SELECT Field1, Field2
    from Table1 WHERE (Field3 =?) AND field3 <> ""';
$stmt = $con->prepare($query);
if ($stmt->execute(array($_POST['FieldInput']))) {
   if ($stmt->rowCount() > 0) {
     $return['error'] = true;
   }    
 }
 $stmt->close();
 mysqli_close($con);
 echo json_encode($return);
 ?>
```

Comment: FYI, your code is mixing between procedural and object-oriented coding style, please choose only one.

Comment: Also, you can only pass an array to `execute()`, when you use PDO, not with mysqli lib

Comment: You are looking for [PDO](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php). Unless of course, you enjoy obtuse code. Then mysqli is spot on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't pass an array of values to `execute()`, you have to use `bind_param()`. That feature is only available in PDO, not mysqli.

And `rowCount()` is a PDO method, not mysqli. It should be the `num_rows` property.

```
$query = 'SELECT Field1, Field2
    from Table1 WHERE (Field3 =?) AND field3 <> ""';
$stmt = $con->prepare($query);
$stmt->bind_param("s", $_POST['FieldInput']);
if ($stmt->execute()) {
    $stmt->store_result();
    $return['error'] = $stmt->num_rows > 0;
}
```

Comment: Now I am getting the same error on the line: `if ($stmt->execute(array($_POST['FieldInput']))) {`

Comment: When changing it to `if ($stmt->execute()) {` the error changes to `Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::rowCount()`

Comment: `rowCount()` is another PDO method. In mysqli it's `$stmt->num_rows`

Comment: You seem to have some serious confusion between PDO and mysqli. I suggest you switch to PDO, it's a much better interface.

Comment: I appreciate your help, I am still learning both styles. For some reason, it always shows `{"error":false}`  as if the parameter is not being passed?

Comment: Is there something else that needs to be adjusted?

Comment: Try adding `$stmt->store_result()`

Comment: No same result, if there are more than one 0 rows it needs to return `$return = ['error' => true];` how can this be done?

Comment: Sorry, it needs to be after `execute()`.

Comment: Thank you @Barmar